# Exception treated as user-unhandled even though it's handled

Tags: visual-studio-2010, exception, unhandled-exception

**Short version:**

Why does Visual Studio tell me that the code has thrown a user-unhandled exception, even though I catch the exception?

**Longer version:**

I'm using Entity Framework together with [Microsoft's transient fault handling framework](http://windowsazurecat.com/2011/02/transient-fault-handling-framework):

My Entity Framework class is partial, and I have my own method SaveChangesWithRetries where I perform the retry-logics:

```
public partial class EfContext
{
    public virtual void SaveChangesWithRetries()
    {
       var retryPolicy = RetryPolicyFactory.GetDefaultSqlCommandRetryPolicy();
       retryPolicy.ExecuteAction(() =>
                       {
                          SaveChanges();
                       });
    }
 }
```

My code which uses this function may look as follows:

```
try
{
    context.SaveChangesWithRetries();
}
catch (OptimisticConcurrencyException)
{
    continue;
}
```

Even though I catch the OptimisticConcurrencyException exception, Visual Studio stops the debugger and tell me that the call to ExecuteAction() threw an user-unhandled exception. When this happens, the debugger stop within the EfContext class. If I press F10, the debugger moves to the catch (OptimisticConcurrencyException).

I don't understand why VS2010 tells me that there was a user-unhandled exception even though I have a catch and even though my catch catches the exception.

Comment: What's that `continue` doing in your `catch`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out what was causing this.

1. Our code started a try/catch clause
2. Our code called Transient Fault Handling Framework (TFHF)
3. TFHF called our code (via lambda expression9
4. Our code threw exception

Since TFHF was built in release, the .NET Framework did not understand that our own code catched the exception in step 0, which was thrown in step 3.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem where I needed an exception to propagate through some .NET code so that I could catch it on the other side. I found that the Debug>Exceptions dialog allows you to select which exception types you want VS to break on. For each Exception type, you can check whether it should break whenever the exception is thrown or only if it's unhandled. So, what I did was choose an esoteric exception type for which "user-unhandled" is unchecked by default and wrap the exception that I wanted to propagate with that type of exception. Specifically, I chose the AppDomainUnloadedException because it's in the System.dll assembly and was, thus, already referenced by my project.

Here's my code that wraps the IOException I was needing to propagate:

```
public override int Read(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
{
    try { return innerStream.Read(buffer, offset, count); }
    catch (IOException ex) { throw new AppDomainUnloadedException("Exception from innerStream: " + ex.Message, ex); }
}
```

And here's my code where I'm catching it on the other side of the .NET code it needed to propagate through:

```
try { bytesRead = sslStream.Read(buffer, offset, count); }
catch (Exception ex) { /* ex handled here. */ }
```

Problem solved. VS no longer breaks on innerStream.Read when it throws the IOException.

Comment: That seems like an ugly solution which sooner or later will cause confusion. :)

Comment: It's a hack for sure, but it does work, which makes it better than nothing. As far as future confusion, that's why we have comments. :)